# java program print null instead of String variable

Tags: java

I made 2 classes one of them is:

```
public class tuna {

    public String girlname;

    public tuna(String name) {
        name = girlname;
    }

    public void type() {
        System.out.println("your girl name is :" + girlname);
    }
}
```

the other is:

```
class apples {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tuna dog = new tuna("nicole");
        dog.type();
    }
}
```

It seems like everything is ok but when I run it it prints:

> your girl name is null

Why? And how to fix that?

Comment: name=girlname -> girlname=name

Comment: use public tuna(final String name) to prevent this error. p.s. in Java, class naming convetion is to begin with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 2):

In the constructor of class tuna, it has to be..
girlname=name;

(You made a typo, I guess... )

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
public class Tuna {

  private final String girlname;

  public Tuna(final String girlname) {
      this.girlname=girlname;
  }

  public String getGirlname() {
    return girlname;
  } 
  ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not assigning values correctly.

In java,the thing on the right is copied to the thing on the left and this is

called associativity of the '=' operator.So instead of writing `name=girlname;`
write it as `girlname=name;`

Answer (score 0):

the order of the assignment if what is making the app behaving weird...

you have this:

```
 public tuna(String name) {
     name = girlname;
 }
```

which means you are writing in the paramener the name of the **girlname**;

you mean for sure instead:

```
 public tuna(String name) {
    this.girlname = name;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class tuna {

public String girlname;

public tuna(String name) {
    this.girlname = name;
}

public void type() {
    System.out.println("your girl name is :" + girlname);
}
```

I'd make this simple change for it to work. Remember, the value of name is now stored in girlname, which is what you want. :)